# Best practice on connecting Activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm writing my first Android app and want to pick up good coding practices. I have an Activity which contains a 2-column grid of all the data items available in the app (listActivity). There's an Activity to create a new data item (createActivity), which is triggered from the listActivity. Now, when the createActivity finishes, what is the best way to handle this situation with respect to the following:

- Should the createActivity store the new data item in the permanent storage and return only the ID of the newly created item to the listActivity OR should it return all the data fields of the item as putExtras() of the returnIntent?
- Should the listActivity 'repaint' the entire data view or should it simply append the newly created data item dynamically? Will the answer to this question change if the listActivity also has to handle delete & edit events? What if the list view is NOT a 2-column grid but a single column list?

Comment: I'm not happy with the question title. Please feel free to suggest something better.

Answer (score 0):

> Should the createActivity store the new data item in the permanent storage and return only the ID of the newly created item to the listActivity OR should it return all the data fields of the item as putExtras() of the returnIntent?

That depends on what your `listActivity` needs to know about the new item. Generally saving the data in storage and only sending back the ID should be enough - based on my answer to some of your following questions. You might also need some indicator of the action that has been performed (Create, edit or delete).

> Should the listActivity 'repaint' the entire data view or should it simply append the newly created data item dynamically?

Yes, if something in the underlying `Adapters` data set has changed a repaint is most probably needed (or at least calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `Adapter`). If the order of the items in the list does not matter, you could just append the item to the list - but I still recommend that you save it in storage and then retrieve it when you want to add it to the `Adapter`. This is also why you would only need to pass the ID around. Also in order to append you would need some way of knowing if the last listitem has one or two columns filled.

> Will the answer to this question change if the listActivity also has to handle delete & edit events?

The edit functionality is basicly the same as created (except the fields have values when you open the edit view). If you delete an item from the list a full repaint of the list is probably the best thing to do, as to not confuse the order of the items.

> What if the list view is NOT a 2-column grid but a single column list?

Appending would be easier - but there is not much difference. In a single column list you might be able to avoid some full repaints that would be needed in a 2-column list - though I don't think it will make much difference.